# Loading Multiple Scripts with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I load multiple script using jQuery AJAX?

Instead of this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax( { url: 'https://www.domaincom/js/script1.js', dataType: 'script' } );
    jQuery.ajax( { url: 'https://www.domaincom/js/script2.js', dataType: 'script' } );
});
```

Something more elegant, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var scripts = [];
    scripts[0] = 'https://www.domaincom/js/script1.js';
    scripts[1] = 'https://www.domaincom/js/script2.js';

    jQuery.ajax( { url: scripts, dataType: 'script' } );
});
```

Comment: If you have to do something like this, I would chain your ajax with callbacks... ie: when the first one is done, call the next one, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/moyijab/1/edit?js,output

```
let url = "https://rawgit.com/moongod101/c2682ecd0b52cdd631b45b94cbc18674/raw/6b3bdeda52f57aa3da0f8ec70eab54e406af76cf/jsbinAJAXScript.js";


let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            let back = xhttp.response;

            let scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
            scriptTag.innerHTML = back;
            document.querySelector("head").appendChild(scriptTag)


    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url);
  xhttp.send();
```